# Change nice level of currently running script

Tags: bash, nice

I would like to change the nice level of the currently running script:

```
#!/bin/bash

nice_it ( ) {
    nice
    ps -o "%p %r %y %x %n %c %a"
}

nice_it
```

That does not work, since `nice` tries to change the nice level of the command started by it.

Is it possible to achieve this in bash?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is pretty trivial.

```
renice -n 10 $$
```

Comment: Sure, that is it. In some systems, `-n` is not accepted.

Comment: For those who don't know, `$$` is the current shell process ID.